# for for other thing than a loop? C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

In my course I need to dynamicly allocate a  list of Cards, but there is one line of this code I'm not sure about.

```
if (newPlayer)                        
{
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> playerName;

    newPlayer->nom = playerName;
    newPlayer->nextPlayer= NULL;
    newPlayer->cardsInHand= NULL;
    if (playersList)                           
    {
        //this for I dont understand. How can a for loop become this and what does it does                  
        for (p = playersList; p->nextPlayer; p = p->nextPlayer);
             p->nextPlayer= newPlayer;
    }
    else                                       
    {
        playerList= newPlayer;
        newPlayer->nextPlayer= NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to take things waaaay slower. First learn exactly what a `for` loop is.

Comment: The for loop is simply advancing to the last item in the linked list. The second line containing the new player assignment is misleading in its indentation. That is, it's not part of the for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's still a loop.  Reformatted:

```
for (p = playersList;     // initialize p to the head of the list
     p->nextPlayer;       // continue while there is a next player 
     p = p->nextPlayer)   // set p to the next player
  ;                       // do nothing inside the loop.
```

Note the semicolon. It was always there, but hard to spot.

Now that we're at the end of the list, point the last element's `nextPlayer` member to `newPlayer`

```
p->nextPlayer = newPlayer;
```

The original should really be indented as:

```
for (p = playersList; p->nextPlayer; p = p->nextPlayer)
  ;

p->nextPlayer = newPlayer;
```

As-is, it's certainly misleading.